# How can I transform an incoming SOAP response into a JSON document using WSO2 ESB

Tags: esb

I would like to convert json to xml using ESB4.10. And need to know and find out how does JBoss ESB support JSON http request? If this has to be done using the HTTP Request do share some thread that I can use to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Within your proxy or REST API element, if you are willing to convert the given response (SOAP) back to JSON just simply include the following properties in your out sequence:

```
<xslt key="ns-remove"/>   
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

---

**Include this section in registry, some generally we need to remove any namespaces available.**

```
<localEntry key="ns-remove">
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml"/>
        <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction() | text()">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```